# MySql Error: cannot connect to local MySql server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2), while other pages do connect correctly

Tags: php, mysql, sockets, cakephp, phpmyadmin

I understand this problem has been a recurring problem on this site, but my issue is a little different than the previous ones.

**PROBLEM**

Some pages use the correct socket directory, while other pages try and connect through an incorrect socket directory or this is what I believe the problem is based on the error i am receiving.

**DETAILS**

HOST: example.com

cakePHP version: 1.3.2 (Not my choice).

Page's content comes from database.

URL: http://example.com

My website has 2 sections:

- anonymous section
- login section for members or admin

The anonymous section works. It accesses the database, adds the content, and funcitons as it should.

**ERROR**

The error occurs when I click a link "view more.." under "Job Links" on the home page. **A login form should pop up**, instead i receive the error "cannot connect to local MySql server through socket  '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)".

In addition, after I login via the "Members login" button, also on the home page, with the correct credentials, it also produces the same error.

**QUESTION**

Why would different sections on my webpage try to access the sockets through different directories?

**ADDITIONAL STUFF**

I signed up today and this is my first post, so feedback on my post regarding enough information would be helpful for future posts.

Thanks for your time.

**UPDATE**

Upon further research, MySql has been using the socket directory /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock from the start. Not sure what this means yet, but continuing research..

**database.php file**

class DATABASE_CONFIG {

```
var $default = array(
    'driver' => 'mysqli',
    'persistent' => true,
    'host' => 'redlabelcom.netfirmsmysql.com',
    'login' => 'bcp',
    'password' => '********',
    'database' => 'bcp',
    'prefix' => '',
    'encoding' => 'UTF8',
    //'socket' => '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock', // I've tried commenting out all variations of socket and port
    //'port' => '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock',   // nothing works.
);

var $test = array(
    'driver' => 'mysqli',
    'persistent' => false,
    'host' => 'redlabelcom.netfirmsmysql.com',
    'login' => 'bcp',
    'password' => '********',
    'database' => 'bcp',
    'prefix' => '',
    'encoding' => 'UTF8',
    //'port' => '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock',
);
```

}
?>

Comment: How many instances of mysql is running?

Comment: @Ron Ross if you are on shared hosting contact you host

Comment: I transferred the site from an existing working site, so the code is all the same. This includes the database as well. I will give you this info now and look for some code that may help you out.

Comment: Have you tried to empty the CakePHP cache directories? If you're running with debug disabled and the cache directories were copied from the old server, this may cause problems. Remove all files from the app/tmp/cache/persistent and app/tmp/cache/models

Comment: Yeah. I deleted the old cache files. Unfortunately, this did not fix the issue :)

Comment: Can you post your database-config from app/config/database.php (without the password of course)? Is it configured to connect via an ip/host or to connect via socket? Are multiple connection-settings defined and in use for some models? Although it's still possible that there's a mis-configuration on the server, you may be able to circumvent it by connecting via tcp/ip in stead of a unix socket

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**PROBLEM SOLVED!**

Thanks everyone for your support!

This was an interesting issue that initially looked more complicated than the actual problem.

cakephp version 1.3.2 is set up to make a new connection to the database if you need to access the phpbb data fields. The new connection uses a different configuration than what is set up in the database.php file.

Below is a detailed description with file locations.

the **'app/webroot/discussion/common.php'** file makes a NEW connection to the database using a different set of MySql parameters than the database.php file. Again, it does NOT use database.php's MySql configuration.

Instead, cakephp defines new connection variables located at:
**'app/webroot/discussion/config.php'**

To solve the problem, simply change the

$dbhost => localhost   -> $dbhost   => yourservername

$dbname  => wrongname   -> $dbname  => rightname

etc..

Keep in mind that it is possible the previous developer changed these values, so if this doesn't help you then good luck.

BTW, the error message above was the result of trying to connect to localhost.

Comment: The error isn't 'trying to connect to localhost', since changing it to 127.0.0.1 would also work. Rather what happens is that you (logically) expect MySQL to connect via TCP/IP when you use 'localhost', but actually, MySQL by default tries to connect to a socket if you use that as the host name. Using a domain name or IP forces a TCP/IP connection.

Comment: I'm sure what you are saying is accurate. However, I just tried using 127.0.0.1 instead of the @server-name and same error occurred. Perhaps it has something to do with my hosting provider?

Comment: In order to keep your website better maintainable, I'd suggest to add a `database_phpbb.php` file inside your `app/Config/` directory (containing the database settings for phpbb) and include *that* inside `app/webroot/discussion/config.php` That way you'll be able to manage all your settings at a single location. Also, the database-settings will no longer be inside your public webroot, which is always a risk in case somebody decides to disable PHP on the server (yup, had that once)

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I will definitely do that.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is really strange. I guess this has something to do with mysql connection. MySQL is a daemon, usually configured in /etc/mysql/my.cnf. There you define how the client will connect the MySQL server:

```
[client]
port            = 3306
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

If your socket is wrong (there's no such socket on the server), you are probably connecting different mysql host/port from anonymous/secured parts of application. This is possible (I mean different db connections from different application parts). Check your configuration (host, port, etc.) and try to connect from MySQL console:

```
$ mysql -h hostname -u username -p dbname # enter password
```

and check if you can connect. If you can connect from console, you'll surely connect from any server-side application (php, python, whatever).

It's an application that someone else was developing, right, and now you have to maintain it?

Comment: Yep. Someone else developed it.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue, I ran the following commands:

mysqld --tc-heuristic-recover=ROLLBACK

systemctl start mariadb.service